# Matlibplot with annotation on hover

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, annotations

I am trying to create a Python code to show a line graphic with matlibplot, and at the same time shows the info of the x and y at the scattered points.
I found this code and it is pretty much what I wanna do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def update_annot(ind, line, annot, ydata):
    x, y = line.get_data()
    annot.xy = (x[ind["ind"][0]], y[ind["ind"][0]])
    # Get x and y values, then format them to be displayed
    x_values = " ".join(list(map(str, ind["ind"])))
    y_values = " ".join(str(ydata[n]) for n in ind["ind"])
    text = "{}, {}".format(x_values, y_values)
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)

def hover(event, line_info):
    line, annot, ydata = line_info
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        # Draw annotations if cursor in right position
        print(dir(line))
        cont, ind = line.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind, line, annot, ydata)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            # Don't draw annotations
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def plot_line(x, y):
    line, = plt.plot(x, y, marker="o")
    # Annotation style may be changed here
    annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(-20, 20), textcoords="offset points",bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
    annot.set_visible(False)
    line_info = [line, annot, y]
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event",lambda event: hover(event, line_info))

# Your data values to plot
x1 = range(21)
y1 = range(0, 21)
x2 = range(21)
y2 = range(0, 42, 2)
# Plot line graphs
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_line(x1, y1)
#plot_line(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

It works ok with random data, but when I try to do the same with real data coming from a file with different columns information I am getting errors.
This is the code I am using:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style


def grafico():
    grafico = "1"
    if grafico =="1":
        input_indice="1"
        x=[]
        y=[]
        style.use("ggplot")
        input_año="2020"
        input_año=int(input_año)
        input_mes = "01"


        # GRÁFICO PARA IBEX35
        if input_indice =="1":
                input_año = str(input_año)
                dt = pd.read_csv('~/Test.txt', delimiter=',')
                dt_fecha = dt.loc[dt['Date'].str.contains(input_año + "-" + input_mes)]
                fecha=dt_fecha.Date
                for row in fecha:
                    fecha=row[5:]
                    x.append(fecha)
                apertura=dt_fecha.Open
                for row in apertura:
                    apertura=row
                    y.append(apertura)
                def update_annot(ind, line, annot, ydata):
                    x, y = line.get_data()
                    annot.xy = (x[ind["ind"][0]], y[ind["ind"][0]])
                    x_values = " ".join(list(map(str, ind["ind"])))
                    y_values = " ".join(str(ydata[n]) for n in ind["ind"])
                    text = "{}, {}".format(x_values, y_values)
                    annot.set_text(text)
                    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)
                def hover(event, line_info):
                    line, annot, ydata = line_info
                    vis = annot.get_visible()
                    if event.inaxes == ax:
                        print(dir(line))
                        cont, ind = line.contains(event)
                        if cont:
                            update_annot(ind, line, annot, ydata)
                            annot.set_visible(True)
                            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
                        else:
                            if vis:
                                annot.set_visible(False)
                                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
                fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                line=plt.plot(x,y,color="red", marker="o")
                annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(-20, 20), textcoords="offset points",bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
                annot.set_visible(False)
                line_info = [line, annot, y]
                fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event",lambda event: hover(event, line_info))
                plt.show()
                sys.exit()
while True:
    grafico()
```

The data in the Test.txt file is this one:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Dividends,Stock Splits
2020-01-02,9639.1,9705.4,9615.1,9691.2,142379600,0,0
2020-01-03,9631.2,9650.7,9581.2,9646.6,135130000,0,0
2020-01-06,9585.4,9618.2,9492.7,9600.9,103520400,0,0
2020-01-07,9623.1,9657.9,9557.9,9579.8,133476100,0,0
```

The graphic is drawn, but when I move the mouse pointing to some of the scattered points I get an error saying:
cont, ind = line.contains(event)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'contains'

The example that works use a range to show in the graphic, but my data is not a range type, it is a list type.
Could you give me a hand with this?
Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to have a much easier way to tackle this type of annotations.

Answer (score 0):

i spent some time why this happens but i couldnt find any. if it helps below one works fine

```
import time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
def grafico():
    grafico = "1"
    if grafico =="1":
        input_indice="1"
        x=[]
        y=[]
        style.use("ggplot")
        input_año="2020"
        input_año=int(input_año)
        input_mes = "01"
        # GRÁFICO PARA IBEX35
        if input_indice =="1":
                input_año = str(input_año)
                dt = pd.read_csv('~/Test.txt', delimiter=',')
                dt_fecha = dt.loc[dt['Date'].str.contains(input_año + "-" + input_mes)]
                fecha=dt_fecha.Date
                for row in fecha:
                    fecha=row[5:]
                    x.append(fecha)
                apertura=dt_fecha.Open
                for row in apertura:
                    apertura=row
                    y.append(apertura)
    def update_annot(ind, line, annot, ydata):
        x, y = line.get_data()
        annot.xy = (x[ind["ind"][0]], y[ind["ind"][0]])
        # Get x and y values, then format them to be displayed
        x_values = " ".join(list(map(str, ind["ind"])))
        y_values = " ".join(str(ydata[n]) for n in ind["ind"])
        text = "{}, {}".format(x_values, y_values)
        annot.set_text(text)
        annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)

    def hover(event, line_info):
        line, annot, ydata = line_info
        vis = annot.get_visible()
        if event.inaxes == ax:
            # Draw annotations if cursor in right position
            print(dir(line))
            cont, ind = line.contains(event)
            if cont:
                update_annot(ind, line, annot, ydata)
                annot.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            else:
                # Don't draw annotations
                if vis:
                    annot.set_visible(False)
                    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def plot_line(x, y):
        line, = plt.plot(x, y, marker="o")
        # Annotation style may be changed here
        annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(-20, 20), textcoords="offset points",bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
        annot.set_visible(False)
        line_info = [line, annot, y]
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event",lambda event: hover(event, line_info))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plot_line(x, y)
    plt.show()
grafico()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, it looks like works pretty well. I kinda do the trick with the library mplcursors and adding the line mplcursors.cursor(hover=True). It works not bad but isn't the best resolution because when there is a lot of data in the graphic the hover action is pretty slow because it shows the data not only at the points but all long the line. So I will take a look careful to your solution which is much better than mine. Apprecitate it.